# Install local extras in Python

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

setup.py of my package X uses setuptools to optionally install an extra package Y, via the `extras_require` parameter.

Now package Y disappeared from PyPi and, as far as I can tell, from the visible Internet. `easy_install X[Y]` fails with `error: Could not find suitable distribution for Y`.

However, I still have a local copy of Y's tarball. Y is a pure-Python package.

What is the best way to modify setup.py to allow this (local?) optional extra?

---

EDIT: The fix is meant to be temporary, until I figure out a proper replacement. I do **not** want to start officially maintaining Y myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick workaround via the `dependency_links` option of setuptools.

1. Upload Y's tarball to some url `http://URL_Y`.
2. Add the line: `dependency_links = ['http://URL_Y'],` to my setup.py.

Now `easy_install X[Y]` works and I didn't have to register Y anywhere. I will delete it from URL_Y as soon as I have a proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass [`setuptools.Command`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#adding-commands) and then overload the default `install` command. Then you could have THAT execute a subprocess that installs the dependency. It's a hack, but that's what you were asking for!

In setup.py:

```
from setuptools import Command
class MyInstallCommand(Command):
    # Overload the 'install' command to do default install but also install
    # your provided tarball. Blah blah blah read the docs on what to do here.

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    # etc ... and then...
    # Overload the 'install' command 
    cmdclass={
        'install': MyInstallCommand, 
    }
)
```

I'm grossly oversimplifying it, but this is the basic gist.

Comment: thx @jathanism, if problems come up with my solution I'll try this one (heavy artillery!) :)